# Why UICollectionView didSelect method does not work?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've created my `UICollectionView` programmatically and in this case my `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method does not call at all.

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), height: 360), collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

So, what is a problem? Why when I tap on the cells I do not get my response?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Selected Cell: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Comment: Delegate object not `nil`?

Comment: 1) Try to set `Background Color` of `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell`. See if it is visible on screen properly or not. 2) Set `userInteractionEnabled` = true on `UICollectionView`

Comment: @pkc456 why? I already see my cells, and already set userInteraction enabled

Comment: @Doe This testing exercise is to cross check the UI elements' position only. Sometime the UI components are override by other views(due to bad autolayout). Or sometime the UI elements' frame are outside but visible on screen thus not getting the click action.

Comment: Try to print `self`. Check if it returns nil or current view controller detail.

Comment: where you added collection view , in self.view then true clips to bounds property and check collection view is still visible

Comment: did you add these to .h? class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource

Comment: Try bring your collectionview front.

Comment: Maybe you've added some gesture recognizer to the vc's view?

Comment: What possibly went wrong in your case according to me is your Viewcontroller does not conform to ***UICollectionViewDelegate*** . more code snippets might be helpful, can you please post it??

Answer (score 14):

i Know this may be late, but for the sakes of feature purpose, `CollectionView[didSelectItem]` not responding to touch could be as a result of you also enalbing `addGestureRecognizer` so check if you have set a gesture recognizer on your `CollectionView` like so `collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestRecognizer)`

Comment: Thank you. This saved my time.
I enabled gesture recognizer on my table view  whose cells contained collectionView and it prevented the delegates from being  triggering

Comment: Thanks. In my case, mistake was I added gesture recognizer on view controller.

Answer (score 9):

I just encountered this case.

Did you put a button or an interactive view in a collection view cell?
Your touch is handled by it, then didSelect isn't called.

Turn off User Interaction Enabled property by Interface builder, or set false programmatically.

[image]

Comment: You Made My Day Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, you should make sure you didn't using `tapGestureRecognizer` on your `view` in the background of `collectionView`.

Answer (score 1):

check in `UiCollectionviewCell` subclass `isUserInteractionEnabled` property or set it programaticaly to true

```
self.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you don't have UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout together.

Comment: What do you do if you need UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ? What about the flow layout breaks tapping cells?

Comment: I think that you have misunderstood the flowLayout. Basically Flowlayout gives you the feature to react on the dimension of the collection view frame and made calculation to bring them to the cell

Try this:

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
let spazio = 10
let width = (yourCollection.frame.size.width/2)-(spazio * 2)
let height = (width * 1.5) + (spazio * 2)
return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
}

Never seen flownlayout break anything

Answer (score 0):

Select ViewController.swift in Project Navigator. Update the class declaration with this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource 


//After class declaration create a new variable:

 var collectionView: UICollectionView!



  override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
   layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
   layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

   collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
   collectionView.dataSource = self
   collectionView.delegate = self
   collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
   collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Selected Cell: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a strange edge case where I had accidentally specified a class for the cell’s container view (and a class that was not valid for the container view), and everything looked fine, I did not receive any warnings, but `didSelectItemAt` would not be called.

That's 5 hours of my life I would like back.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was implementing `hitTest` in UICollectionView's parent view to intercept hit event, so `didSelectItemAt` did not call.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let p = convert(point, to: v)
    if v.point(inside: p, with: event) {
        return v.hitTest(p, with: event)
    }
    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```