# How to push a navigation view using collectionView didSelectItemAt?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am writing a code for my school project. As a beginner would, I looked up on tutorials on youtube how to code. 
To summarize the hierarchy of my used objects:

Main `collectionView` (first one loaded) for scrolling `horizontally` between views.

List `collectionView` for listing cells.

`collectionViewCell` cells for listing information.

However, I am unable to find a way so that when I call a `didSelectItemAt` function by tapping on one of the cells to push a new `view`. I have tried creating a function that pushes the view in the `MainViewController` and call it by creating an instance of the `class` in `didSelectItemAt` function but I had no luck.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why UICollectionView didSelect method does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036197/why-uicollectionview-didselect-method-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

have you added datasource and delegate?. if you added please check cell click working or not. if click is working add bellow navigation code.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Contributing to Raj's answer, if you want to push a view controller when selecting some specific item in your collection view, just a slight variation of condition will do the trick, this delegate method is called with you click on an item in your collection view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    if indexPath.item == **<your item's index>** {
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the upper Side the Class like this :

```
    class tableViewVC : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
}
```

Add inside ViewDidLoad():

```
tableView.delegate = self
  tableView.datasource = self
```

And then you will use in TableView Method like this  :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let ViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController!, animated: true)
}
```